# How to set the path OSX applications use

Tags: osx, environment-variables, path, gui, osx-finder

I'm running Mountain Lion 10.8.4, and have my environment all customized through `~/.profile` so that when I run GUI apps like [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com) or Eclipse from the command line

```
open /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app
```

they inherit my `$PATH` settings, allowing the app to run external commands not in OSX's very limited default path. However, I'd really like to be able to open programs through Finder or the Dock and give them the same path I use on the command line. `launchctl setenv PATH $PATH` doesn't work in 10.8. How do I set this up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Note

*This no longer works with more recent versions of OS X, including 10.10 Yosemite (I'm not sure about 10.9 Mavericks). It does work with 10.8 Mountain Lion, however.*

It's actually not too hard, but you do need to have admin privileges (using the `sudo` command to write to `/etc`).

1. From Terminal (or your favorite substitute), see if there's anything in the file `/etc/launchd.conf`:

   ```
   cat /etc/launchd.conf
   ```

   If you get an error like

   > cat: /etc/launchd.conf: No such file or directory

   then continue with the next step. If the `cat` command does display some content, copy it.
2. Determine your system's current path, as we'll need to make sure we include it later:

   ```
   launchctl getenv PATH
   ```
3. In your favorite editor, create a new text file with the following content, modified to fit your needs:

   ```
   setenv PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/Users/YourUserName/bin:/path/to/gems/bin
   ```

   Make sure you've included the **entire** contents of the path from the previous step, otherwise you'll break your system.

   If the `cat` command from Step 1 displayed some content, paste it into the new file **before** the `setenv PATH` command. If it already contains a `setenv PATH` command, just modify it to add the extra directories you need.
4. Save the new file *in your home directory* (`/Users/YourUserName`) as `launchd.conf`.
5. Go back to Terminal and enter:

   ```
   sudo mv ~/launchd.conf /etc
   ```

   to use admin power to move the new file to `/etc`, *replacing anything that was there before*. Depending on your previous usage of the [`sudo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html) command, you may get a short "be careful doing what you're doing" message, but either way you'll need to enter your password. `/etc` is not directly accessible through the Save dialog of graphical editors unless you're a real power user and know how to get around OSX's file system restrictions.
6. ***Reboot your computer***

And you should be all set. If you're interested, [`launchd`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html) and [`launchctl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html) use the `csh`/`tcsh` syntax, so you can't use the `bash`/`zsh` `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:...` format.

Comment: It's said this no longer works since OS X Yosemite; see discussion in http://stackoverflow.com/a/588442/822138

Comment: @sam I know :( I recently got a new iMac with 10.10 on it, tried the launchd hack, and it didn't work. I'd appreciate any pointers to an updated working method.